# Web (Rest/SOAP) API for Moodle Question Bank

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I need to make a different front-end I need good API interface for Question Bank/Question Engine? I didn't find much details on this.. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a web service for the question bank

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

If you know PHP, then you could create your own web service in Moodle

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external

First you will need to create a simple local plugin

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/local

At the very least, have these 2 files

```
local/yourpluginname/version.php
local/yourpluginname/en/local_yourpluginname.php
```

Then add a web service to the plugin

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service

Declare your web service in this file

```
local/yourpluginname/db/services.php
```

And add the code for the web service to something like

```
local/yourpluginname/classes/external/get_questions.php
```

The class will need 3 functions, what parameters are required, what parameters are returned and code for the web service

```
namespace local_yourpluginname\external;

use external_function_parameters;
use external_multiple_structure;
use external_single_structure;
use external_value;

class get_questions extends \core_external\external_api {
    public static function execute_parameters() {
        ...
    }

    public static function execute_returns() {
        ...
    }

    public static function execute($params) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.    
I am using Moodle 4.1.2 (MOODLE_4012).
I am creating the web application that's why I need API from Moodle and I have found this web services wsfunction=core_course_get_courses to get all courses from moodle that is fine and it worked.
so I am also looking is there any web services to get all the question from moodle question bank. If yes then help for this.
I tried but could not get success. I want a simple documentation for this from where I can see the endpoint for the question bank and simply call them to get those question from question bank.